# Small Information in SAPI Grammar tonGrmmar Builder?

Tags: c#, sapi

How do we load a grammar file .xml into GrammarBuilder class, so that i will pass my grammar builder to the engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GrammarBuilder.AppendRuleReference() is the answer finally i got it with the help of Glorsoft